# Skill-based routing for chat

Tags: community, chat, omnichannel

We are trying to implement skill-based routing for a chat. We have only one type of skill - language. We have customers in multiple countries. They are always logged into our community. We would like to route the chats to agents based on the language of the customer. But when a new `LiveChatTranscript` record is created, `ContactId` field is empty. It gets populated only once the chat is accepted or missed. Is there any way how I can get the Contact language when the chat request is created? I know there is option to use `BrowserLanguage` field but that is not reliable enough.

Comment: The language can be picked up from the browser and passed into the chat transcript when the chat is initiated. Examples of passing parameters into the transcript through our embedded service- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_prechat_details.htm?search_text=sample

Also, are you using an uptodate version of the chat button with embedded services, or visualforce pages?

Comment: @Swetha we are using embedded services. And we don't want to pick up the browser language, since it is not reliable, and we also already know the language of the logged-in user since it is on his User and Contact as well.

Comment: You can pass in the language in the invocation. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_prechat_details.htm